# How to use event delegation without using on method?

Tags: jquery

The contents are loaded from ajax and now I wanted to hide a paragraph but cannot achieve.

I know there is event delegation like:

```
$('closest_selector').on('click','selector',function(){});
```

But I simply wanted to hide the paragraph like this:

```
$('.myclass').next().hide(); //doesn't hide
```

But if I do this:

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){
    $(this).next().hide();//hides
});
```

So, how can I use event delegation for this:

```
$('.myclass').next().hide(); //so that it would hide.
```

Comment: `$('.myclass').next().hide();` has to be executed after the ajax loads the content... look at how the content is loaded using `.load()` or a version of `$.ajax()` then use its callback to execute the script

Comment: If the element is there, it should work. Use it after ajax success.

Comment: I don't want to include my code within $.ajax() code, is there any way?

Comment: another option is to use css's [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) like `.myclass + * {display: none}`

Comment: Can I use $(document).on('load',function(){ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use deferreds for this purpose:

```
function someOperation(){
 //ajax stuff
 return $.ajax(...);
}

// then somewhere in your code:

someOperation().done(function () {
  $('.myclass').next().hide();
});
```

Or you can use event bus for this:

```
var eventTopic = $.Callbacks();

someOperation().done(function (params) { eventTopic.fire(params); })

// then somewhere in your code:
eventTopic.add(function () {
  $('.myclass').next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to write the code in your ajax success, then the least you can do is to check if it is done! simply set a global variable (e.g. window.succeed=true) in your ajax success, and then check if it is set to true or not, true would be succeeded and typeof window.succeed=='undefined' would be failed or still trying!

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){       
    if(window.succeed==true){
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(window.succeed==true){
        $('.myclass').next().hide();
    }
},500);
```

UPDATE2:

the previous update checks it again and again, even after the ajax is completed and the task is done, now if you want to do it only once, you need to use the below code:

```
var checkAjax=setInterval(function(){
    if(window.succeed==true){
        $('.myclass').next().hide();
        clearInterval(checkAjax);
    }
},500);
```

now if the ajax call is completed, the code executes the hide event and then stops checking again.

Comment: But you still called a click event.

Comment: if you dont wanna call a click event, you can put the function in an interval and let it check by itself!